# MySQL Sum of Field Divided By Product Of Two Others

Tags: mysql, math, sum

My knowledge of MySQL is pretty limited, so I hope I am not asking a really stupid question.

What I am attempting to do is calculate the value of one field divided by the product of two other fields.

Something like:

```
(sum(salesorderlinedetail.rate) / (salesorderlinedetail.metalweight) * 
(salesorderlinedetail.spotprice) AS `Premium`
```

What this might look like in raw numbers would be:

```
850 / (1646 * 0.5) = 1.03281
```

I am attempting to make this result appear as another column for every row of data returned from the query.

I'm guessing this probably requires a subselect statement somewhere.

Comment: provide your query and table structure, by editing the question.

Comment: Why are you taking the `SUM()` of `salesorderlinedetail.rate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your "raw numbers" example and simply do replacement (hint: it's all in the parenthesis):

```
850 / (1646 * 0.5)
850  ==> salesorderlinedetail.rate
1646 ==> salesorderlinedetail.metalweight
0.5  ==> salesorderlinedetail.spotprice

salesorderlinedetail.rate / ( salesorderlinedetail.metalweight * salesorderlinedetail.spotprice)
```

No need for SUM(), as that will introduce indiscriminate aggregation (unless there are details you have yet to share with us :-)

Comment: Wow, it hit me minutes after I asked the question. You guys are fast and you are all correct. Thank you very much for the help in this! My apologies for the rather simple, time-wasting question.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select column1,column2,(    
UPDATE TableName 
SET Column2 = sum(salesorderlinedetail.rate) / ((salesorderlinedetail.metalweight) *   (salesorderlinedetail.spotprice)) from TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

select column1, column2, (sum(salesorderlinedetail.rate) / (salesorderlinedetail.metalweight  * 
salesorderlinedetail.spotprice) AS Premium from salesorderlinedetail;